# Oracle SQL Question, Looking for rows that don't contain specific values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have seen answers to this that get close, but don't quite do it for me.

Imagine that you have a several strings. You want to find the rows in an existing table that contain these strings and the rows that don't.

To find the rows that do contain the strings in a column is, of course, easy, e.g. myTable has the following columns:

- myTableID  varChar(3)
- myTableValue varChar(20)

With the following rows:

```
ABC | The First Row
GHI | The Second Row
JKL | The Third Row
```

```
select * 
from myTable 
where myTableID  in ('ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL');
```

myTable doesn't contain a row with a value of 'DEF' in column myTableID. The answer set would correctly not contain a row for that. There isn't one!

However what I want to be able to do is treat this like a bit like like a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the value 'DEF' in front of a set of columns that contain nulls. Giving the following kind of result:

```
ABC| ABC | The First Row
DEF| null|null
GHI| GHI|The Second Row
JKL| JKL|The Third Row
```

I have several hundred key values that I need to look at.

Does anyone here have any thoughts about the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I have several hundred key values that I need to look at.

That's a lot of values to write manually. I would suggest putting them all in a table, say in a `myref(id)`.

You can then generate the expected resultset with just a `left join`:

```
select
    r.id,
    t.*
from myref r
left join mytable t on t.id = r.id
```

Comment: I like this answer. Keeps it simple and allows for the criteria to be controlled by another table.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am actually not writing them manually, but receiving them from an unrelated system. If I were then this would work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection or a `VARRAY` and a table collection expression with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` is a built in `VARRAY` that you could use:

```sql
SELECT t.COLUMN_VALUE AS id,
       y.*
FROM   TABLE(
         SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL' )
       ) t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table y
       ON ( t.COLUMN_VALUE = y.id )
```

Or you can define your own collection:

```sql
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
```

and use it:

```sql
SELECT t.COLUMN_VALUE AS id,
       y.*
FROM   TABLE(
         stringlist( 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL' )
       ) t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table y
       ON ( t.COLUMN_VALUE = y.id )
```

which would output:

> ```
> ID  | ID   | VALUE         
> :-- | :--- | :-------------
> ABC | ABC  | The First Row 
> DEF | null | null          
> GHI | GHI  | The Second Row
> JKL | JKL  | The Third Row
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83b195203c51830e9ce5a9f1059e0271)*

You can also pass the collection/`VARRAY` as a single bind variable.

Comment: Definitely trying this, thank you. I didn't know about creating types. I hope my DBAs have given me that possibility.

Comment: @Chrisb There are many built-in collection types that you can use without needing to define a new type (if your DBA allows access to them); the `SYS.ODCI*LIST` types are one example.

Comment: Thanks @MT0 that was exactly what I wanted. Kudos! I used the CREATE TYPE method.